# How to split the payment received in Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to split the payment into 2 accounts, the main and the secondary. Like any other marketplace or service platform, the secondary account is owned by the platform itself. I've read that it is called parallel payments under adaptive payment in Paypal. But right now, they don't accept new integration.

I've also read about the new mass payment and checkout features, but I'm not sure if they are the same. What I want to have is similar to fiverr where when a customer pays, the payment is automatically split into 2 just like I described above.

Any idea what section in Paypal docs I should read? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mass Payments is old, it's been replaced by Payouts, which you could [request access to](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts).  It may or may not be approved for your marketplace use case.